# Почему Telnet моментально обрывает связь?

Tags: windows, smtp, telnet

OC: Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise 64 bit
CLI: Cygwin64

Проверяю почтовый сервер с помошью telnet. Соединения проходит, но моментально соединение обрываеться. Консоль выдает:

```
elok_testauto_gui@MUC-APP ~
$ telnet muc-app.domain.com 25
Trying 10.51.143.213...
Connected to muc-app.domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

В настоязий момент пытаюсь настроить grafana alert который должен посылать сообщения с помощью smtp. Уже несколько дней натыкась на проблемы и не могу локализовать что именно не работает smtp-сервер или grafana.

Может ли вышеуказанная сообение означать неполадки с smtp сервером и как их устранить?
Буду рад вашей помощи

Дополнение:

- Если написать письмо в форме txt файла и поместить в C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup файл отправляеться и приходит на мою почту (но не на почту моего сотрудницы. У него другой домен, может это причина?)
- в mail.err при проверке фичи grafana ничего не записываеться. Я так понимаю между ними нет коннекта.

Comment: А почтовые программы работают?

Comment: Так через netcat порт открой и попробуй к нему подключиться

Comment: В mail.err что написано?

Comment: добавил инфу в описание

Comment: Через localhost к порту подключись

Comment: Какой SMTP сервер?